# Assigning attributes to a control upon creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Just wondering if it was possible to not split the following steps...

```
Button b = new Button()
{
    // You can access Attributes here, but only get, not set.
    ID = "btnExample",
    Text = "Click Me"
};

b.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('hello, world')");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drive from Button and add it to the constructor:

```
class MyButton: Button
{
    MyButton(MyAttributes atr)
    {
       for each (elm in atr)
       {
          base.Attributes.Add(elm.Key, elm.Value);
       }
    }
}
```